# Django user signup / registration form not working

Tags: jquery, python, django

I made a sign up form following a tutorial.

what im trying to do as you can see here is to have the data transferred and get an error or success message to the targeted div in response without refreshing the page.

i have set the 3 forms : email ,email2 and password in the index.html

but the site is not doing anything, and apparantly it doesn't work.

I am also getting the

TypeError:  is not JSON serializable

error.

I think im doing something wrong here.

can you explain to me what im doing is wrong?

thanks.

index.html

```
    <script>

// using jQuery
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});

</script>


<div class="signup_div">
<form id="signup_form" method="post" action="">
{% csrf_token %}

          <div class="field-wrap">
          <!--<label>
            Email Address
          </label>-->
          <input required="" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email address">
        </div>

        <div class="field-wrap">
        <!--<label>
          Email Address
        </label>-->
        <input required="" type="text" name="email2" placeholder="Email address">
      </div>

        <div class="field-wrap">
          <!--<label>
            Password
          </label>-->
          <input required="" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>

        <button class="ladda-button forgot" data-color="mint" data-style="slide-up"><a href=""><span class="ladda-label">Forgot Password?</span></a></p></button>

        <button class="ladda-button button-primary login_button" data-style="slide-up"/><span class="ladda-label">Sign Up</span></button>

        </form>
</div>

          <script>

            $('#signup_form').on('submit', function(e) { e.preventDefault()
              formdata = $('#signup_form').serialize(); formdata.csrfmiddlewaretoken = '{{ csrf_token }}';
                $.ajax({
                  type:"POST",
                  data: formdata,
                  url: '{% url 'signup' %}',
                  error: function(response){
                    $('.login_div').text(response.error)
                  },
                  success: function(response){
                    <!--console.log(response);-->
                    $('.signup_div').text(response.success)
                      $('.signup_div').text(response.error)
                  // do something with response
               }
              });
            });
          </script>
</body>
</html>
```

views.py

```
    def ajax_signup(request):
    form = UserSignupForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        new_user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=password)
        login(request, new_user)
        data = {'form': form, 'success': 'success'}
    else: data = {'form': form, 'error': 'error'}

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
```

and forms.py

```
    from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, get_user_model, login, logout

class UserSignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Confirm Email')
    email2 = forms.EmailField(label='Confirm Email')
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'email2',
            'email',
            'password'
        ]
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        email2 = self.cleaned_data.get('email2')
        if email != email2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Emails must match")
        email_qs = User.objects.filter(email=email)
        if email_qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("This email has already been registered")
        return email
```

Comment: Actually you are passing a form in your data dictionary. This is a class instance. you cannot pass a class instance in json dictonary.

Comment: um. could you please explain in detail? (I only started to learn this thing few days ago, and im not very good :( )  and how could i fix this then?

Comment: You are trying to return a form in a json response, this form variable is a class instance it is not JSON serializable. So remove form in ``data = {'form': form, 'success': 'success'}``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As correctly pointed out by [Nikhil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38503189/django-user-signup-registration-form-not-working/38503774#comment64405258_38503189), you are trying to serialize a form instance. Instead, you should serialize the form data.

From the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#field-data):

> Whatever the data submitted with a form, once it has been successfully
>   validated by calling is_valid() (and is_valid() has returned True),
>   the validated form data will be in the form.cleaned_data dictionary.

Also, `form.cleaned_data` will not be available if is_valid() does not return True. You can instead use `request.POST`

Instead of:

```
    data = {'form': form, 'success': 'success'}
else: data = {'form': form, 'error': 'error'}
```

You want to do:

```
    data = {'form': form.cleaned_data, 'success': 'success'}
else: 
    data = {'form': request.POST, 'error': 'error'}
```